# BroadcastReceiver notification not sent for android.media.tv.action.INITIALIZE_PROGRAMS

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-tv

Broadcast which should be sent to the application just after app is installed on TV is not received.

I declared BR in Manifest.xml:

```
<receiver
   android:name=".RunOnInstallReceiver"
   android:exported="true">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.media.tv.action.INITIALIZE_PROGRAMS" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I declared also:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />
```

`RunOnInstallReceiver` class is very simple:

```
public class RunOnInstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Log.v("RAMPS", "Broadcast received");
  }
}
```

I tried with nVidia Shield and Mi Box 3 - no success. Anyone had similar problem?

Comment: I had the same issue with you, even I used adb shell am broadcast -a android.media.tv.action.INITIALIZE_PROGRAMS -n com.your.app.package/.YourReceiver. But it was not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you side loading the application? INITIALIZE_PROGRAMS is only sent when the application is installed via the store.

When side loading (installing from adb or android studio), you can trigger the intent with:

`adb shell am broadcast -a android.media.tv.action.INITIALIZE_PROGRAMS -n com.your.app.package/.YourReceiver`

Answer is from bullet #5 in Android developer guide for creating a channel on the home screen: https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/recommendations-channel#creating_a_channel

Answer (score 1):

In my case, if you use `product flavor` you should trigger by:

`adb shell am broadcast -a android.media.tv.action.INITIALIZE_PROGRAMS -n X/Y`

**`X`** is your applicationID.
**`Y`** is the link of your broadcast received file in your project.

*Example*: *You build your application with Build variants *staging* and trigger is*:

`adb shell am broadcast -a android.media.tv.action.INITIALIZE_PROGRAMS -n com.google.android.staging/com.google.android.tvhomescreenchannels.RunOnInstallReceiver`

Here is ApplicationId:
[image]

Here is path RunOnInstallReceiver:
[image]